# Why can't I get past CAPTCHA after changing Google Account password?

Tags: google-account, password

I changed my Google Account password, and now there's a notification about trouble logging into my Gmail account on my Samsung Galaxy S. That's fine, I'd expect that.

What I don't expect is a pop-up box containing a CAPTCHA, that I cannot get past. I'm sure I got at least one of them right (despite the auto-caps for start of words tripping me up a few times). It just keeps popping up with another CAPTCHA.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you try from the Gmail client and the browser?

Comment: Yeah, I did... no go. I tried it again just now, and it worked! Must have been something up server side. Thanks for the comment, tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis seemed to solve itself. After trying again just now, it worked. Must have been a server-side thing. Sorry I can't help anyone else that has this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try unlock the captcha: https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
Then, go back to your android phone e retype o password.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the endless Captcha. There is a solution though.

Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha on a PC or a web-browser and unlock the Captcha for your account. You will then be able to login again with username and password on your device.

Hope this helps